# Facebook login : Make email mandatory

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

We are using facebook for login in our website.

We need email as a mandatory permission. If the user doesn't grant email permission then the dialog should give an alert() message saying 'Please grant email permission' and repeat.

 I have seen this feature in few of the shopping sites. The below code works fine but doesn't have the feature I mentioned.

Help needed.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'MY APP ID',
                oauth: true,
                status: false, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true // parse XFBML
             });
    };

    function fb_login() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken; //get access token
                user_id = response.authResponse.userID; //get FB UID

                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    // you can store this data into your database
                    alert(response.email);
                });

            }
        }, {
            scope: 'email'
        });
    }
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
```

Somewhere in the body of HTML.

```html
<div class="span"><a onclick="fb_login();"><img src="css/images/facebook.png" alt=""/><sm>Sign In with Facebook</sm><div class="clear"></div></a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#checking
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web#re-asking-declined-permissions

especially the "Handling Missing Permissions" part of the first link.

> When an app requests permissions, people may completely deny those permissions, not fully grant those permissions, or change them later. In order to provide a great experience, apps should be built to handle these situations.
>
> - First, apps should be able to handle any permissions that were requested but not granted:
> - Check granted permissions before trying to use APIs that require them.
>   Detect permissions errors returned when an API request is made without the correct permission.